# Is it possible to combine Query-By-Example with spring data method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, query-by-example

I have a `Template` class with several fields `(id,name,description,created,modified....)`

and can filter by created date like below:

```
public interface TemplateRepository extends JpaRepository<Template, Long> {
    Page<Template> findAllByCreatedBetween(OffsetDateTime createdStart, OffsetDateTime createdEnd, Pageable pageable);
}
```

My Example like this:

```
ExampleMatcher exampleMatcher = ExampleMatcher.matchingAll()
                .withIgnoreCase()
                .withStringMatcher(ExampleMatcher.StringMatcher.CONTAINING)
                .withIgnoreNullValues()
                .withIgnorePaths("id");
Example<Template> templateExample = Example.of(requestTemplate, exampleMatcher);
```

Is there any possible way to add the Example into `findAllByCreatedBetween` method?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Test
public void givenPassengers_whenFindByExampleCaseInsensitiveMatcher_thenExpectedReturned() {
    ExampleMatcher caseInsensitiveExampleMatcher = ExampleMatcher.matchingAll().withIgnoreCase();
    Example<Passenger> example = Example.of(Passenger.from("fred", "bloggs", null),
      caseInsensitiveExampleMatcher);

    Optional<Passenger> actual = repository.findOne(example);

    assertTrue(actual.isPresent());
    assertEquals(Passenger.from("Fred", "Bloggs", 22), actual.get());
}
```

See this link:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-query-by-example

Comment: `findOne` & `findAll` worked with `Example` but it is not my case.